# python pandas mean by hour of day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with the following dataset with hourly counts in columns. The dataframe has more than 1400 columns and 100 rows.

My dataset looks like this:

```
CITY      2019-10-01  00:00     2019-10-01  01:00    2019-10-01  02:00     ....      2019-12-01  12:00

Wien            15                    16                       16          ....              14                                                              
Graz            11                    11                       11          ....              10
Innsbruck       12                    12                       10          ....              12
  ....
```

How can I convert this datatime to datetime such as this:

```
CITY          2019-10-01         2019-10-02               2019-10-03       ....          2019-12-01 
              (or 1 day)         (or 2 day)               (or 3 day)                     (or 72 day)
Wien            14                    15                      16           ....              12                                                              
Graz            13                    12                      14           ....              10
Innsbruck       13                    12                      12           ....              12
  ....
```

I would like the average of all hours of the day to be in the column of the one day. 
The data type is:

```
type(df.columns[0])
out: str

type(df.columns[1])
out: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
days = df.columns[1:].to_series().dt.normalize()
df.set_index('CITY').groupby(days, axis=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
           2019-10-01  2019-12-01
CITY                             
Wien        15.666667        14.0
Salzburg    12.000000        14.0
Graz        11.000000        10.0
Innsbruck   11.333333        12.0
```